# Find the probability of choosing at least many objects out of a set

Tags: probability

We are given 10 chocolates of which 6 are of high quality (hq). One may chose 5 out of 10. What is the probability of choosing at least 3 of the hq ones ? If we denote by $A_3, A_4, A_5$ the events of choosing $3,4$ or $5$ hq ones, then assuming the events are independent (I do not know how to explain these events are independent), then $\mathbb{P} (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=  \mathbb{P}(A_1) + \mathbb{P} (A_2) + \mathbb{P} (A_3).$ The number of options of choosing 5 elements out of 10 is $\frac{10!}{5!5!}.$ The number of possibilities of choosing 3 hq out of six is $\frac{6!}{3!3!}.$ Similarly, we find the options for picking 4 and 5 hq. We get $\mathbb{P} (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)= \frac{\frac{6!}{3!3!}}{\frac{10!}{5!5!}} + \frac{\frac{6!}{4!2!}}{\frac{10!}{5!5!}} + \frac{\frac{6!}{5!1!}}{\frac{10!}{5!5!}}.$ It turns out that the result is wrong if I compare it to my book. I will appreciate if you help me find the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, you don't mean independent, you  mean disjoint. When $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)$.

Second, the issue is how you are calculating $\mathbb{P}(A_k)$. The number of ways to choose $k$ hq's is ${6 \choose k} \cdot {4 \choose {5 - k}}$. Why is that? Its because when you pick $k$ hq's, you also need to pick $5 - k$ low quality chocolates. So, for example

$$\mathbb{P}(A_3) = \frac{6!}{3!3!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!}.$$

You should be able to do this for $A_4$ and $A_5$ as well.

Comment: Thanks. Why are $A_3, A_4, A_5$ disjoint, i.e. how can one show that ?

Comment: @user996159 they are disjoint by definition. You can't simultaneously choose exactly 3, exactly 4 and exactly 5 of something, can you?

Answer (score 0):

You have $10$ chocolates, this forms the set $S$. The set $S_h$ is your $6$ hq chocolates. The set $S_r$ is your remaining $4$ regular chocolates.

Observe that $S_h$ and $S_r$ is a partition of $S$

Now choose $3$ hq chololates in $S_h$, you have $\binom{6}{3}$ choices. However for each such choice, you can choose $\binom{4}{2}$ regular cholocates in $S_r$. Thus, you have $\binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{2}$ possible choices.

The same reasoning for $4$ hq chololates gives $\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{1}$ possible choices and $\binom{6}{5}\binom{4}{0}$ for $5$ hq chololates.

The total number of choices is $\binom{10}{5}$, by consequence your probability is:
$$
\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{1} + \binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{31}{42}
$$